# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' al cargar sql

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, mysql-workbench, mariadb

Versión: **Server version: 10.1.32-MariaDB**

Tengo problemas para establecer una contraseña en `mysql o mariadb` uso `xampp 5.6`

Instalo xampp entro en la consola y con `mysql -u root` me logueo bien.

Siguiendo diferentes ejemplos que he visto por distintas páginas web he probado diferentes formas de cambiar la clave, cada vez he desinstalado he instalado de nuevo el xampp.

Prueba 1:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('clave');
```

Prueba 2:

```
# mysqladmin -u root -p password clave
Enter password:

PC-CASA@DESKTOP-11KK10F c:\xampp
# mysql -u root -pclave
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3
Server version: 10.1.32-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql
Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]>
```

---

Probando cualquiera de las dos formas si accedo desde la consola o el workbench accede perfectamente, si reinicio el mysql también accede perfectamente.

El problema viene cuando cargo un `*.sql` con 2 bases de datos, la carga se hace correctamente veo las tablas y todo, pero cuando reinicio el mysql al intentar acceder de nuevo me arroja el error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Prueba

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'clave';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'clave'' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: yo para MYSQL y MARIADB uso este comando y me funciona perfecto para modificar la contraseña ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nuevopassword';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente, yo tengo en mi equipo de cómputo

1. MySQL 8
2. MariaDB 10.3

Aunque no trabajo con XAMPP, hago el cambio de contraseña de este modo

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nuevacontraseña';
```

1. root o el equivalente de nombre de usuario que tu tengas
2. localhost o el equivalente de tu equipo de cómputo
3. nuevacontraseña aquí vas a poner la contraseña nueva que deseas asignar *se cuidadoso con la que escribes*

Si el cambio ocurrió de manera exitosa deberías ver un mensaje similar al siguiente

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

PRUEBA 1. MYSQL 8

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nuevopassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)
```

PRUEBA 2. MariaDB 10.3

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nuevopassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```

> Para ambas situaciones, una vez hecho el cambio y que visualices dicho
>   mensaje, cierra la terminal y trata de iniciar sesión pero con la
>   nueva contraseña que tu establezcas

Aquí te dejo un enlace oficial a la documentación de MySQL que lo explica mas a detalle, sin embargo como te muestro en el ejemplo también funciona para mariaDB

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Hola he probado con la sentencia que me dices: ALTER USER pero me da ERROR 1064 (42000). ¿Puede ser por la versión? veo que usan la función password('clave')

Comment: pon aquí el comando completo como lo escribiste, @nachfren

Comment: Edito la pregunta, creo que es por mi versión de mariadb 10.1

Comment: @nachfren ya trataste con este tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Comment: Voy a probar a bajarme la última versión de mariadb ya que en otro pc lo instalé sin demasiado problemas. Pruebo tú sentencia y aviso. Gracias.

Comment: saludos y mucha suerte @nachfren

Comment: al final lo he conseguido como tu me decías pero he cambiado el xampp por el MySql Server. Con ese tambien me ha funcionado con mysqladmin -u root -pclave desde el cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente. Entra a la cuenta root de mariadb con mysql -u root -p. Introduce tu contraseña, si es que tienes. Crea el nuevo usuario introduciendo:

```
CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contrasena';
```

Ahora dale permisos a tu usuario introduciendo:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';
```

Si quieres que tenga acceso a todas las bases de datos. En caso contrario:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB_NAME.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';
```

Sales de mariadb. Entras de nuevo con el nuevo user: mysql -u nombre_usuario -p. Introduces tu contraseña. Y aplicas tu sql.

Comment: pero aquí no esta modificando la contraseña, solo esta creando un nuevo usuario y asignandole privilegios